# mapbox map not showing in div

Tags: html, mapbox

a new learner here. I found this template from bootstrap that i want to use. But i cant seem to get my map to show on my div.

Basically what im trying to create is when a user clicks on tab1, the map for tab-1 will show and so on for tab-2. But i cant seem to get the map to show in my div

Can someone please help me?

## **here's my html: **

```
<section id="services" class="services section-bg">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <div class="section-header">
      <h2>ADAKAH ANDA BERADA DI KAWASAN BERISIKO BANJIR?</h2>
      <p>Gunakan simulasi banjir menggunakan data JUPEM untuk semak kawasan anda</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row gy-4">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs row  g-2 d-flex">
          <li class="nav-item col-3">
            <a class="nav-link active show" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab-1">
              <h4>Rekod Banjir Dari 2020 hingga 2022</h4>
            </a><!-- End tab nav item -->

            <li class="nav-item col-3">
              <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab-2">
                <h4>Simulasi Banjir Menggunakan Data JUPEM</h4>
              </a>
            </li><!-- End tab nav item -->
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active show" id="tab-1">
            <div class="col-lg-6 order-2 order-lg-1 mt-3 mt-lg-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
              <div id='map'></div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End tab content item -->

          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
            <div class="row">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End tab content item -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

## and here's my js:

```
//MAP REPORTED CASES
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZW5haW1hbnN5YWhtaSIsImEiOiJjbGFhaWNmamIwNzA4M25vM2d5cDFrYjFjIn0.ZUhZjJVocvsakOr_nLaufw';
function mapinit(){


var darkmode= L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'jupem.gov.my',
    id: 'mapbox/dark-v10',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZW5haW1hbnN5YWhtaSIsImEiOiJjbGFhaWNmamIwNzA4M25vM2d5cDFrYjFjIn0.ZUhZjJVocvsakOr_nLaufw'
});
    var map = L.map('map',{
        center:[4,102.5],
        zoom: 7,
        // layers:[osm,darkmode,hujanberterusan,ribut]
        layers:[darkmode,banjir2022,banjir2021,banjir2023]
    });

    var baseMaps = {
        "Basemap": darkmode,
        // "Basemap": osm,
    };
    var overlayMaps = {
        // "Hujan Berterusan": hujanberterusan,
        "Banjir 2022":banjir2022,
        "Banjir 2023":banjir2023,
        "Banjir 2021":banjir2021,
    };

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlayMaps).addTo(map);
}
    // kes-kes hujan berterusan
        contoh1 = L.marker([2.018309,103.075749]).bindPopup('Banjir di Yong Peng, Johor pada Dis 2022'),
        contoh2    = L.marker([2.014791, 103.309122]).bindPopup('Banjir di Kluang, Johor pada Dis 2022'),
        contoh3    = L.marker([1.832312, 103.310333]).bindPopup('Banjir di Simpang Renggam, Johor pada Nov 2022'),


    // kes-kes hujan berterusan
        contoh4    = L.marker([2.508421, 102.827294]).bindPopup('Banjir di Segamat, Johor pada Jan 2023');

        contoh5    = L.marker([3.150853, 101.693001]).bindPopup('Banjir di Bulatan Dato Onn, Kuala Lumpur pada Jan 2021');
        contoh6    = L.marker([3.149269, 101.696682]).bindPopup('Banjir di Masjid Jamek, Kuala Lumpur pada Jan 2021');
        contoh7    = L.marker([2.987956, 101.574396]).bindPopup('Banjir di Kampung Sungai Baru, Selangor pada Jan 2021');
        contoh8    = L.marker([3.205303, 101.511526]).bindPopup('Banjir di Sungai Buloh, Selangor pada Jan 2021');
        contoh9    = L.marker([3.077582, 101.551214]).bindPopup('Banjir di Seksyen 13, Shah Alam, Selangor pada Jan 2021');

    // var hujanberterusan = L.layerGroup([contoh1, contoh2, contoh3, contoh4]);
    var banjir2022 = L.layerGroup([contoh1,contoh2,contoh3]);
    var banjir2023 = L.layerGroup([contoh4]);
    var banjir2021 = L.layerGroup([contoh5,contoh6,contoh7,contoh8,contoh9]);
```